# Does Gaming Meta's icon look like a lost life?

Tags: discussion, meta, logo

While Gaming's logo looks right, Meta's logo reminds me of the lost life from "Video Games took my life" joke.

While it is traditional way of converting logos for Meta, should it be more optimistic?

Comment: Well by the time you're talking about talking about video games, you probably have.